# Индикатор загрузки пока выполняется GET запрос axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, get, axios

Делаю `GET` запрос на страницу для загрузки контента, запрос с помощью `axios`
**файл `app.js`**:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    axios.get("/get-cards")
        .then(response => {
            $("#content").html(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`)
        });
});
```

**страница где находится `#content`:**

```html
<div id="content">
    <!-- сюда загружается контент -->
</div>
```

**страница на которую отправляется запрос (по адресу "/get-cards)":**

```html
@foreach($technics as $technic)
    <div class="technic-card">
        <div class="card-img-slider">
            <img src="{{ $technic->img_1 }}" alt="{{ $technic->name }}">
            <img src="{{ $technic->img_2 }}" alt="{{ $technic->name }}">
            <img src="{{ $technic->img_3 }}" alt="{{ $technic->name }}">
        </div>
        <div class="card-name">{{ $technic->name }}</div>
        <div class="card-type">{{ $technic->type }}</div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="card-price">{{ $technic->price }}/час</div>
            <div class="card-buy-btn">арендовать</div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

И когда только загружается страница где находится `#content` страница грузится 1-2 секунды, **как сделать чтобы вместо загрузки окна был индикатор загрузки в `#content`(`div` блок с анимацией загрузки) до тех пор пока не выполнится запрос?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно просто изначально поместить его в код страницы

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="my-spinner">...</div>
</div>
```

он будет отобржаться сразу после загрузки и будет заменён на контент, когда придёт ответ с сервера

Comment: хорошая идея. но я думал будет что то вроде метода для отслеживания "пока выполняется"

Comment: в целом, необходиости в таком методе нет. достаточно принять, что запрос выпоняется между вызовом `axios.get()` и получением ответа в `then` или `catch`. соответсвенно, в общем виде логику запроса с отслеживанием состояния можно описать так:
`    funciton request(url) {
         onRequestStarted(); // наша функция, в которой происходят действия перед началом запроса, например заменяем контент на индикатор загрузки
          axios.get(url)
               .then(response => {onRequestFinish(response)})
               .catch(error => ...);
    }`

Comment: а как сделать чтобы на вкладке браузера не было загрузки. т.е. чтобы индикатор загрузки был только на станице?